# How do I exclude imports from my TypeScript build?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, yarnpkg, es6-modules

I have a JS file that imports a module:

```
import { LitElement, html } from '../lib/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js';
```

This causes a load of TypeScript errors, some due to versions, some due to a test framework used by some of the modules, some due to different `noImplicitAny` or `strictNullChecks` settings, but most due to Yarn flattening the npm hierarchy (and not rewriting internal references).

None of these are errors in my code, and I'm not even referencing the TS directly - most are coming from the TS source for that JS file.

How do I stop these from breaking my build? I don't care whether the source or test TS files compile in place, I only need the result JS file.

Even in TS files I don't want TSC to recompile the referenced Yarn modules - at most it should use them for type checking (and even then prefer a `*.d.ts` file over the source).

I've tried `--noResolve` and that doesn't fix it (and also breaks the `es2017` `lib` references).

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more details? In particular which version of lit-element are you using and can you also include the polymer code of the module where you are using lit-element?

Comment: @univ `"lit-html": "^0.10.0"`, `"@polymer/lit-element": "^0.5.1"` and the relevant line of my code is `import { LitElement, html } from '../lib/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js';` (`lib` is where Yarn is putting my npm modules). However, this isn't an issue with `lit-element` as such (although it exhibits the issue), more that it, in turn, assumes `import ... from '@polymer/...'` will work.